# Двоичная куча. Индексы левого и правого соседа вершины

Tags: алгоритм, дерево

Читаю про двоичную куча и там есть фраза, что
двоичную кучу удобно хранить в виде одномерного массива, причем левый потомок вершины с индексом i имеет индекс 2*i, а правый 2*i+1 если нумерация идет с 1 (для 0 соответственно 2*i+1 и 2*i+2).

Не могу понять ПОЧЕМУ это верно? Как это математически доказывается, что левый сосед имеет индекс 2*i+1, а правый 2*i+2?

**UPDATE**
Вывел сам :)

Пусть у нас есть дерево

```
       1
      / \
    2     3
  /  \   / \
 4    5  6  7
/ \   /
8  9  10
```

Возьмем в качестве примера число 5 с индексом 5.
Пусть оно находится на уровне `j` в дереве. Тогда при такой нумерации его индекс равен сумме количества нод на уровнях `1` - `(j-1)` (пусть это число `K`) плюс `L` нод слева от него на уровне `j + 1`.
Итак, `X = K + L + 1`, где K={1,2,3}, L={4}. Пусть так же кол-во элементов справа от X на том же уровне будет `М`, то есть M={6,7}.

Выразим теперь индекс левого потомка X через то что мы знаем, `X' = K + L + 1 + N + 2*L + 1`.
Если мы докажем что `N + 2*L + 1 = K + L + 1`, то отсюда будет следовать что `X' = 2X`

Докажем это:

```
N + 2*L + 1 = K + L + 1

N + L = K
```

Вспомним что `K` - геометрическая прогрессия от `1` до `2^(j-1)` => ее сумма равна `2^j - 1` => `K = 2^j - 1`

`N + L` = количеству элементов на уровне `J` за вычетом одного (X) => оно равно `2^j - 1`, что и требовалось доказать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что значит математически доказывается? Хранение в одномерном массиве -- это всего лишь простой способ представления двоичной кучи в памяти; вершины вообще можно хранить как угодно, лишь бы можно было однозначно поставить в соответствие индексы массива вершине и ее потомкам, то есть так, чтоб две различные вершины кучи вдруг не попали в одну и ту же ячейку массива. Приведенные вами способы (для индексации с единицы и с нуля) просто самые явные, наглядные и очевидные.

Вы вполне можете левого потомка хранить по индексу `2*i + 1`, а правого по индексу `2*i`. Можете хранить элементы в обратном порядке (тогда для дерева из `N` вершин корневая вершина будет иметь индекс `N`, а левые и правые потомки вершины с индексом `i` будут иметь индексы `2*i - N - 1` и `2*i - N - 2`). Разницы с точки зрения реализации алгоритмов нет никакой. Повторюсь, главное, чтобы никакие две вершины не попадали в одну и ту же ячейку; способы же, приведенные вами, -- самые очевидные и наглядные, которые этому условию соответствуют.

Чтоб до конца осознать это, советую нарисовать пару-тройку двоичных деревьев на бумаге, а потом для каждого из них заполнить массивы по различным приведенным формулам (индексация с единицы) (а еще лучше выдумать еще пару-тройку других):

- `left(i) = 2*i`; `right (i) = 2*i + 1`;
- `left(i) = 2*i + 1`; `right(i) = 2*i`;
- `left(i) = 2*i - N - 1`; `right(i) = 2*i - N - 2`.

Для следующего 7-элементного дерева (N = 7)

```
         1
       /   \
     2       3
    /  \    / \
   4    5  6   7
```

у вас получатся такие массивы:

- `| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |` (ну вот очевидно, самый простой способ);
- `| 1 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 |`;
- `| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |`.

Вы можете реализовать саму кучу, явно выделив функции `left` и `right`, и меняя реализации оных на любые, которые ставят вершинам индексы в однозначное соответствие, алгоритм всегда будет работать, хоть сами вершины будут храниться по-разному.

Comment: хорошо, а можно ли как-то доказать что кол-во элементов справа на том же уровне от элемента Х плюс количество элементов слева от левого потомка Х (очевидно на следующем уровне) всегда равно i - 1, где i - это индекс элемента Х, если ноды считать просто слева направо и сверху вниз?

Comment: А зачем? Это свойство не двоичной кучи, а именно данного вами способа ее хранения.

Comment: да, я понимаю :) мне просто при изучении алгоритмов и структур всегда интересно как до каких-то вещей приходят, и вот отсюда как раз этот вопрос и возник, ведь индексы 2i и i не с балды взяты, они отражают математическую связь
ps я уже вывел как это выходит, сейчас update сделаю

Comment: Этот способ просто самый очевидный и наглядный, из примеров выше это вроде ясно. Я могу подумать над доказательством того факта, что вы хотите доказать, просто я сходу не вижу, какой из него полезный смысл для реализации самой кучи в виде массива.

Comment: да это мои ночные заморочки )))я прекрасно понимаю что это полезного смысла для реализации нет, Вы правы абсолютно.
плюсанул Ваш ответ за помощь мне в любом случае и потраченное время, могу принять если считаете, что это то, что надо )

Comment: Ну, принимать или нет, дело ваше :) Я лишь попытался ответить на ваш первоначальный вопрос :)